# Get property returns empty variable when try to get Target Link Libraries information

Tags: c++, cmake

I have some debug info in CMake to check if I have added no needed info compiling a project. This piece of code works propertly:

```
 # Include DIRECTORIES
  GET_PROPERTY(dirs DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
  FOREACH(dir ${dirs})
    MESSAGE(STATUS " * Include directory: '${dir}'")
  ENDFOREACH()
```

But when I try to check all libraries linked in current project, I get an empty variable:

```
# Linking against
      GET_PROPERTY(libtargets DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} PROPERTY LINK_LIBRARIES)
      MESSAGE("Libs: ${libtargets}")
      FOREACH(libtarget ${libtargets})
        MESSAGE(STATUS " * Target Link library: '${libtarget}'")
      ENDFOREACH()
```

Checking [CMake documentation 3.0](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/get_property.html?highlight=get%20property#command:get_property) it seems ok, but I don't know what values are available to read. I print the info *AFTER* make `ADD_LIBRARY`/`ADD_EXECUTABLE`

Is the `LINK_LIBRARIES` an incorrect value to `GET_PROPERTY`? How could I get that information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Directories don't have the `LINK_LIBRARIES` property according to this page:

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-properties.7.html?highlight=properties%20targets#properties-on-directories

Also I think `target_link_libraries` would have effect only on the target on which it was called, not on the directory. Try using [`get_target_property`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/get_target_property.html?highlight=get_target_properties) instead.

Comment: GET_TARGET_PROPERTY(libtargets ${PROJECT_NAME} LINK_LIBRARIES) works propertly. Thanks.